# Fetch does not return and getting data fails while network receives it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch

My problem is that I get a response from the BE but I'm unable to assign it to a variable in the FE. This is my code:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/classes/all', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })

      if(response.ok){
      const classes = await response.json();
        console.log('classes' + classes);
        this.setState({
          classes,
          selectedClass : classes[0],
          selectedSubject : classes[0].subjects[0].name
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
      alert(error.stack);
    }
  };
```

And the network returns an array of 4 classes, so no problem there... I'm wondering what it up with my code?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Yeah - "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at App.componentDidMount (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:171:40)". Which honestly tells me nothing :(

Comment: One error I can see is the call to `fetch`. `fetch` takes only 2 params. You need to merge the 2nd and 3rd params. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch.
You probably also want to check `response.ok` before trying to parse with `json()`.

Comment: ok, I updated my code accordingly, but I'm still unable to assign it. It never gets to response.json() since the response.ok returns false :(

Comment: Partially it did. I removed it. Turns out I had to set CORS in the BE and now it works like a charm. Thanks :)